# Weekly automated check to see if a script is still present in a homepage

Tags: scripting, website, html, alerts

I work with several hotels that installed a script (unique for each) in their website to add some tools offered by my company. Sometimes they change their home page or their booking engine without realizing that the script must be installed again, so we end up losing days of data till someone realizes that the script is not there anymore by inspecting the page.

I was wondering if there is a way for me to set up a weekly alert or something similar that informs me whether all these scripts are still in place or if they went missing. Is this possible? I have very, very basic IT knowledge so I don't know if I'm asking something stupid or impossible, please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: Well, the answer to "if it is possible" of course is "yes". Asking for the "how" is off topic here though. You should check out monitoring solutions, Wikipedia has a comprehensive list of open source and proprietary tools.

Comment: And, why weekly? You could check every five minutes, and catch the problem soon enough to fix it without "losing days of data".

Comment: Not sure about the details, but this might be as simple as fetching their page and looking for "youscript.js" in the result ...